# Find distance between two points. Time and Speed

Tags: solution-verification

An urgent message had to be delivered from the house Of the Peshwas in Pune to Shivaji who
was camping in Bangalore. A horse rider travels on horse back from Pune to Bangalore at a
constant speed. If the horse increased its speed by $6km/h$, it would take the rider $4$ hours less
to cover that distance. And travelling with a speed $6 km/h$ lower than the initial speed, it would
take him $10 hours$ more than the time he would have taken had he travelled at a speed $6kmph$
higher than the initial speed.
Find the distance between Pune and Bangalore.

I tried my best to solve this in a very short period of time but I couldn't do it all. Such a long process. Then I understood that it could be done using the concept of **integral difference in ratios** Where I end up with wrong result.

I might be wrong with the equations I am forming:
$$(d/s)-(d/(s+6))=4$$
$$(d/(s-6))-(d/(s+6))=10$$

$$6d=5(s^2-36)    \quad ----2$$
$$6d=4s(s+6) \quad ----1$$

from one and two equations, s= 6 and -30

what next?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your 2 equations. The first one simplifies to $6d=4s(s+6)$. The second one can be replaced by $(d/(s-6))-(d/s)=6$ (its difference with the first one), which simplifies to $6d=6s(s-6)$. The system is now easy to solve: $s=30,d=720$.

Comment: I need to look into it. Still its confusing

Comment: I think you meant the second to be $$(d/(s−6))−(d/s)=10$$, no its giving me a wrong result still.

Comment: I just added a hint. If this helps, you may delete your last comment if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I think the velocity times time equals distance formula is easier.

$v t=d$

$(v+6)(t-4) =d$

$(v-6) (t-4+10)=d$

Solve those three equations for $v$,$t$,and $d$(velocity, time, distance), you will get 30, 24, and 720 respectively.

Comment: I didnt  understand, could you be little more in detail.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Do you know the formula velocity * time = distance?  All three equations represent that.  The first represents the original velocity and time.  The second increases the velocity by 6 and reduces the time by 4.  The third reduces the original velocity by 6 and increases the time of the second case by 10.  Of course, the distance is the same in all three cases.